# Why CommandBarFlyout showing only eleven buttons maximum?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I need to create a CommandBarFlyout with many buttons.

My XAML code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Height="40" Width="40">
        <Image Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"/>
        <Button.Flyout>
            <CommandBarFlyout>
                <AppBarToggleButton>
                    <AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
                        <BitmapIcon UriSource="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"/>
                    </AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
                </AppBarToggleButton>
            </CommandBarFlyout>
        </Button.Flyout>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

If I copy-paste twelve buttons in CommandBarFlyout - only first eleven are showing.

If I add more buttons - still first eleven shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/command-bar-flyout#commands-and-content) about Commandbarflyout, it mentions:

> Unlike CommandBar, primary commands do not automatically overflow to
>   the secondary commands and might be truncated.

So the reason why only 11 buttons are displayed should be that the actual contents have overflowed the scope of the primary command and were truncated.

If you still want to continue to use CommandBarFlyout, you can also add commands to the **SecondaryCommands** collection. Or as the document said, to use **CommandBar** or **Flyout**.

Comment: how the scope of primary commands is determined ? Content of CommandBar is truncated if there is no space. But content of CommandBarFlyout is truncated even if there is enough space.

Comment: It should be internal design since we can't see the style of CommandBarFlyout. By testing, the total width of primary commands is about 440. In addition, what do you mean about "But content of CommandBarFlyout is truncated even if there is enough space"? If I showed less than eleven buttons, they can display well, were not truncated. Can you show more details about this?

Comment: I mean that content is truncated even if the window is of 1000 pixels, and there is much space available for CommandBarFlyout

Comment: It has set the width of the primary commands internally, so even if the width of window is 1000 pixels, it won't affect the primary commands.